# Zend Layout using different templates in different controllers

Tags: zend-framework, layout

Struggling with Zend layout, I have 2 templates 1 for homepage and 1 for other pages.  The layout is define in my application.ini

resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

The 2 template files sit it /application/layouts/scripts/

homepage.phtml
layout.phtml

On the hompage controller I want to use the homepage.phtml and for the rest of the site use layout.phtml.

I have searched and search but no joy please help!

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your homepage controller, do:

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('homepage');
```

You can do this in each action, or, if you want it to fire for all actions, in the init() method.

Comment: Cheers!  That simple hey shame i couldnt find it in the documentation! Cheers again Alex.